# Avocado plant browning!

Tags: plant-health, fruit-trees, avocado

I don’t know why.I’ve had it for two years. It’s pretty young. Once I put it in soil, it started browning. I moved it into a room that gets more light, but that doesn’t seem to be helping. I pruned it, fertilized it, and pretty much did everything I can. * side note, during checking for root rot, I broke the two halves of the seed. I don’t know if that’s okay. I put them back together*[image]

Comment: I know it sounds like I’m a rookie but I’m not.

Comment: Might it be a [transplant shock](https://thegardenprepper.com/avocado-tree-transplant-shock/)?